# Phone calls not working on Macbook Air M1

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ios, call

For unknown reason I don't receive incoming calls on my Macbook Air M1 when someone tries to call my iPhone. I've connected apple ID and registered trusted devices. Both devices are logged into the same account email. I've enabled Calls on Other Devices on the iphone.

Macbook Air M1 is using:     `Big Sur 11.6.1`

iPhone X is using:           `iOS 15.2`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

All right, I had to enable `facetime` on the mac including the option to `receive calls from iPhone`.

Maybe this helps someone in the future.